# How does Python import modules from .egg files?

Tags: python, module, package

How can I open `__init__.pyc` here?

```
    >>> import stompservice
    <module 'stompservice' from 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\stompservice-0.1.0-py2.5.egg\stompservice\__init__.pyc'>
```

All I see in `C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\` is the .egg file, but where are the internal files of the package?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/PythonEggs

.egg files are simply renamed zip files.

Open the egg with your zip program, or just rename the extension to .zip, and extract.

Comment: great ! I was not knowing that.

Answer (score 34):

For example, if you want to import the suds module which is available as .egg file:

In your python script:

```
egg_path='/home/shahid/suds_2.4.egg'

sys.path.append(egg_path)

import suds
#... rest of code
```