# Another Python Path Issue

Tags: python, python-2.7, path

I am using Redhat Linux, and the default Python version is 2.6, so I installed Python 2.7.4 on /user/local/bin folder and modified the shell profile, so when I do:

```
$which python
/usr/local/bin/python
```

which is good.

Since I don't have super user permission of the box so I tried to install the Python libraries to a folder that I have write permission. So this is the structure of my libraries:

I created a folder called

```
/share/python
```

And under that folder, I created another folder called library where I put all the python library source folders. Say I want to install the [pyes (Python Elastic Search)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyes/) package. I first downloaded the source_folder, tar unzip and cd into the folder. Then I did

```
python setup.py install --prefix=/share/python
```

Then the installation finished successfully([I have done this before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18173401/python-import-library-from-tar-gz)) and created two library folders under

```
/share/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

And they are

```
urllib3-1.6-py2.7.egg 
pyes-0.20.1-py2.7.egg
```

And when I open Python. Print out sys.path to double check my customized library path has been included. This is what it said:

```
>>import sys
>>print sys.path
['','/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/...'..., '/share/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

And I am pretty sure python knows where to find the pyes and urllib3(installed as dependency). however, I still cannot load the library and the error looks like this:

```
>>> from pyes import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pyes
>>> import urllib3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named urllib3
```

Any idea why would this happen?

Updated:
You need to add those new egg folders into your path and it will work:
Still not quite sure why python setup.py install created two eggs folder but don't add them to the path.

Comment: you cannot get access to the python-egg file , it forbidden

Comment: @drabo2005 permission issue? those two folders' owner is me and the permission level is drwxrwsr-x, which I think is good enough. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851420/how-does-python-import-modules-from-egg-files):

> http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/PythonEggs
>
> .egg files are simply renamed zip files.
>
> Open the egg with your zip program, or just rename the extension to
>   .zip, and extract.

["A small introduction to Python Eggs"](http://mrtopf.de/blog/en/a-small-introduction-to-python-eggs/)

Comment: It might exist as a zipped file in Windows but in Linux I cannot see how it is zipped. However, your answer is very inspiring and I tried to add those two egg folders into the Python path and it worked now.. I am wondering why python setup.py install didn't add that for me...

Comment: I've updated my answer with a link that might help you understand how eggs work

Comment: Do you know why the python install prefix command doesn't add the new created egg folders to the python path? Is there anything I can do to auto include the egg folders in this case.

Comment: No I don't know. I actually don't really use eggs manually. The only thing I do with them is installing them from pypi. What is this egg?

Comment: Just a folder which contains the module of pyes(python elastic search) and urllib3 (one of the dependencies)

Comment: `sudo pip install pyes urllib3` ?